# Can't create Oracle Sql Package Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, package

I am trying to create a package containing stored procedures using in Oracle

When it comes to compiling and execution after checking all table fields are brought down,

I have got `SQL statement ignored` and  `ORA-00926 for VALUES`

Would you please tell me if there is any guidelines for checking these errors or what syntax I should be focusing on ?

Below is my SQL script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TESTAS 
    PROCEDURE GETREPORT01 IS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "TRUNCATE TABLE TESTER.TEST_TB1";

            INSERT INTO TESTER.TEST_TB1
                SELECT 
                    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
                    SERVICE_ADDRESS_ID, 
                    BILLING_CYCLE, 
                    CUSTOMER_STATUS,  
                    CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
                    SUKET_NEW
            FROM 
                ABC.DWH_BUCKETS
            WHERE 
                CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'DIY'
            ORDER BY 
                DECODE(CUSTOMER_STATUS, 'AC', 1, 'IN', 2, 3) DESC;
    END GETREPORT01;
```

Comment: What are the columns of TEST_TB1 ?

Comment: ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
                    SERVICE_ADDRESS_ID, 
                    BILLING_CYCLE, 
                    CUSTOMER_STATUS,  
                    CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
                    SUKET_NEW

Comment: If the code in your question is the full code you are using, I think you need to close the package in the end

Comment: did you check the column type for your table `ABC.DWH_BUCKETS` if matches with your table `TESTER.TEST_TB1`?

Comment: since according to ora manual: `ERROR MESSAGE ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword CAUSE OF ERROR
You tried to execute a SQL INSERT statement and missed the VALUES keyword.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST IS 
PROCEDURE GETREPORT01;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST AS 
    PROCEDURE GETREPORT01 IS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "TRUNCATE TABLE TESTER.TEST_TB1";

            INSERT INTO TESTER.TEST_TB1
                SELECT 
                    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
                    SERVICE_ADDRESS_ID, 
                    BILLING_CYCLE, 
                    CUSTOMER_STATUS,  
                    CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
                    SUKET_NEW
            FROM 
                ABC.DWH_BUCKETS
            WHERE 
                CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'DIY'
            ORDER BY 
                DECODE(CUSTOMER_STATUS, 'AC', 1, 'IN', 2, 3) DESC;
    END GETREPORT01;
END;   
/
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you are missing the `IS` keyword in the first line, and the `END;` in the last line

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TESTAS IS

    PROCEDURE GETREPORT01 IS
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "TRUNCATE TABLE TESTER.TEST_TB1";

            INSERT INTO TESTER.TEST_TB1
                SELECT 
                    ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
                    SERVICE_ADDRESS_ID, 
                    BILLING_CYCLE, 
                    CUSTOMER_STATUS,  
                    CUSTOMER_TYPE, 
                    SUKET_NEW
                FROM 
                    ABC.DWH_BUCKETS
                WHERE 
                    CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'DIY'
                ORDER BY 
                    DECODE(CUSTOMER_STATUS, 'AC', 1, 'IN', 2, 3) DESC;
    END GETREPORT01;

END TESTAS;
```